# Why does if statment return true?

Tags: c, embedded

Advanced C question:Why does if return true?

```
unsigned int i = 8; 
int j = -16;
    if(i+j > 5){
        printf(">5 = %d\n",i+j);
    }else{
        printf("<5 = %d\n",i+j);
    }
```

Comment: You need to deal with `unsigned` here. This is _not_ an advanced question, sorry.

Comment: sorry,for me as a beginner it is

Answer (score 1):

When a `signed int` is operated with `unsigned int` then it is converted to `unsigned int`. Since `-16` can't be represented as `unsigned int`, maximum value that can be represented ny `unsigned int` (`UINT_MAX`) is added to `-16`.

Comment: *"Since -16 can't fit into unsigned int"* It's not a matter of not *fitting*.